# How to get just the last two lines of standard output of command DIR?

Tags: cmd, directory, findstr

The command I am executing is the following:

```
dir >> dir.txt
```

I would be interested in redirecting only certain lines to the txt, for example the last two lines. How can I do that? It occurs to me with `findstr`,  but I don't know how.

Comment: Aside, the sort order is not documented (at least not by the help command) so perhaps you'll want to specify it. Ex: `dir /O D` See `help dir`

Comment: This is clearly an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It looks like you want to get the number of files in a directory or the total number of bytes of the files or the number of directories in a directory or the free space in bytes on a drive as this is output on last two lines of a standard `dir` output. You should ask how to get those data instead of how to get just the last two lines of `dir` output. There is batch file code posted multiple times on Stack Overflow for getting all those data.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) match will isolate those two lines based upon them being the only two lines beginning with two spaces:

```dos
Dir | FindStr /BC:"  " >> "dir.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are under Windows, you can use the Win32 port of the Unix tail command from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tailforwin32/ and then issue the piped command:

```
dir | tail --lines=2
```

This shows the last 2 lines

Hope this helps

Comment: To get some *nix goodness quickly, 0) install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) 1) [`choco install gow`](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Gow)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with PowerShell that you already have on your machine.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "& cmd.exe /C dir | Select-Object -Last 2 | Out-File -FilePath '.\dir.txt' -Encoding ascii -Append"
```

Alternatively...

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "& cmd.exe /C dir | Select-Object -Last 2" >>dir.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple batch file to get output the last two lines of standard output of command `dir` with language dependent information about

- number of files in directory,
- total number of bytes of the files in directory,
- number of subdirectories in directory,
- free space on partition in bytes.

`dir` excludes by default directories and files with hidden attribute set because of using implicit `/A-H` if `dir` option `/A` is not used at all.

Here is the batch file to get displayed the last two lines of output of `dir` executed without any parameters on current directory which of course can be different to directory containing the batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SummaryFiles="
set "SummaryFolders="
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('dir') do (
    set "SummaryFiles=!SummaryFolders!"
    set "SummaryFolders=%%I"
)
if defined SummaryFiles echo !SummaryFiles!
if defined SummaryFolders echo !SummaryFolders!
pause
endlocal
```

The output done by the two `echo` can be also redirected into a text file using for example

```
(   if defined SummaryFiles echo !SummaryFiles!
    if defined SummaryFolders echo !SummaryFolders!
) >DirectorySummary.txt
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`